# Spring REQUIRES_NEW propagation waiting for parent transaction

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, deadlock, spring-transactions

please look into the following code snippets, here is the summary -

1. A service named `ServiceA` which has a method `methodA` is annotated by `@Transactional` annotation.
2. It calls a service `ServiceB`'s method `methodB`, it doesn't have any annotation.
3. `methodB` calls 2 methods `updateA` and `updateB` in the exact order, implemented by `RepositoryA` and `RepositoryB` respectively. Both `updateA` and `updateB` both are dao methods which update 2 different tables having no relation with each other.
4. `updateB` is annotated by `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)`.
5. I am using hibernate `SessionFactory` to implement update for both the methods using native query.
6. Database is Postgres 14.
7. Sping boot version - 2.0.3.RELEASE
8. Hibernate version - 5.4.24.Final

So if you run the code, intermittently, the follwing locks occur, which leads to a dead lock.

1. `updateA` is waitng for `clientRead`. || wait_event_type : `Client` and wait_event : `ClientRead`.
2. `updateB` is waiting for `updateA`. || wait_event_type : `Lock` and wait_event : `transactionid`.

**ServiceA**

```
@Service
public class ServiceA {

  private final ServiceB serviceB;

  public ServiceA(ServiceB serviceB) {
    this.serviceB = serviceB;
  }

  @Transactional
  public void methodA() {
    
    serviceB.methodB();
    
  }
}
```

**ServiceB**

```
@Service
public class ServiceB {

  private final RepositoryA repositoryA;
  private final RepositoryB repositoryB;

  public ServiceC(RepositoryA repositoryA, RepositoryB repositoryB) {
    this.repositoryA = repositoryA;
    this.repositoryB = repositoryB;
  }

  public void methodB() {

    repositoryA.updateA();
    repositoryB.updateB();

  }
}
```

**RepositoryA**

```
@Repository
public class RepositoryA {

  private final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

  public RepositoryA(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
  }

  public void updateA() {

    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
        .createNativeQuery("update tablename1 set time = now() where id = :id")
        .setParameter("id", 1)
        .executeUpdate();
  }
}
```

**RepositoryB**

```
@Repository
public class RepositoryB {

  private final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

  public RepositoryB(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
  }

  @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
  public void updateB() {

    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
        .createNativeQuery("update tablename2 set time = now() where id = :id")
        .setParameter("id", 1)
        .executeUpdate();
  }
}
```

1. Want to understand why `updateB` is depending on `updateA`?
2. Is REQUIRES_NEW asynchronous?

## Expectations

I ran the code in a loop, and it's very hard to replicate the issue as it is intermittent. In most of the runs, following locks occur -

1. `updateA` is waitng for `clientRead`. || wait_event_type : `Client` and wait_event : `ClientRead`.
2. `updateB` is waitng for `clientRead`. || wait_event_type : `Client` and wait_event : `ClientRead`.

But intermittently that's not what happens and as explained earlier following locks happen and leads to a deadlock.

1. `updateA` is waitng for `clientRead`. || wait_event_type : `Client` and wait_event : `ClientRead`.
2. `updateB` is waiting for `updateA`. || wait_event_type : `Lock` and wait_event : `transactionid`.

Sping boot version - 2.0.3.RELEASE
Hibernate version - 5.4.24.Final

Comment: Sping boot version - 2.0.3.RELEASE
Hibernate version - 5.4.24.Final